# Ubuntu Server 10.04 stuck during bootup trying to start gearmand

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

I installed gearmand (0.20) from source yesterday on an Ubuntu Server 10.04 environment of mine. I shut down the environment last night and when I started it back up this morning, it's stuck during the boot up process trying to start gearmand.

Any idea how I can go about fixing this?

**Edit:**

I ended up booting into Single User mode and removing `gearman-job-server` out of `/etc/init.d`. Fixed her right up!

Answer (score 0):

Check the init script to make sure it's daemonizing properly.  Did you install it via a package or from source?

Comment: Installed it (0.20) from source, but how can I go about checking the init script when I can't get the machine to boot?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in startup code of `gearmand`, as described in [Gearmand Bug #771486](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gearmand/+bug/771486). In short, gearmand is started as root, with instructions to switch to another user and daemonize. Main process forks and waits for child to signal about successful startup. Child switches to new user and then fails to signal child (permission denied). So, master process waits for signal forever, and, thus, script in `/etc/init.d`.

So, one should wait when this bug gets fixed or manually adjust startup script to workaround it.